# 'pular' vs. 'saltar' em português europeu?

Tags: português-europeu, uso-de-palavras

Há, para os falantes nativos de português europeu, alguma distinção entre os verbos 'saltar' e 'pular'?

Por exemplo, são aceitas as seguintes frases com qualquer um dos verbos? Há alguma preferência?

> **O gato *pulou/saltou* do telhado.**
>
> **O gato *pulou/saltou* em mim.**
>
> **Eu tive que *pular/saltar* para alcançar a corda.**
>
> **Eu *pulei/saltei* de alegria.**
>
> **Ele *pula/salta* corda.**
>
> **Li quase todas as páginas, só *pulei/saltei* duas.**
>
> **Vou *pular/saltar* o almoço.**

Falantes de outras variantes também podem comentar sua própria percepção.

Comment: Brasil, SP, SBC. Eu não vejo nenhuma diferença de significado puro. Mas acho que "saltar" é um pulo mais curto, porque eu não falaria instintivamente "ele saltou para a atmosfera" — não estou dizendo que ficaria estranho, porque não ficaria. Também acho que só falaria "saltaram o muro", se os agentes (saltadores)  tivessem pulado o muro sem lhe encostar. Também acho eu que "saltar" possa ter um final, um lugar em que "pousou", mas desse tenho 0% de certeza ou confiança. Acho que só falaria "saltar o almoço" em referência ao verbo "pular", mas não acho errado, só incomum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na minha experiência de nascido e criado em Portugal, é assim:

### Só *saltar*

> Saltar à corda
>
> Li quase tudo; só saltei duas páginas; saltei uns parágrafos

### Preferência por *saltar*

> Saltei o muro; saltei o ribeiro
>
> O cavalo saltou por cima do carro
>
> O gato saltou do telhado
>
> O gato saltou-me em cima (dá a ideia que me atacou)
> O gato saltou-me para cima; saltou para cima de mim
> O gato saltou-me para o colo; para o ombro
>
> Tive de saltar para alcançar a corda

### Preferência por *pular*

> Pulei de alegria
>
> Ele foi ao baile e fartou-se de pular (’dançar energicamente’)
>
> A criança anda sempre aos pulos; não se cansa de tanto pular

Nunca ouvi *saltar* ou *pular o almoço*. Encontrei nalguns, raros, livros, e fico com a sensação que é uma adaptação do inglês *to skip lunch*. Se tivesse de escolher, diria *saltar o almoço*, mas o mais natural é mesmo dizer “hoje não almocei”.

Depois de pensar nestes exemplos todos, a minha conclusão é a seguinte. Em Portugal, *saltar à corda* é expressão fixa, como em *saltar ao eixo* ou *saltar à vara*. Tendemos a usar *saltar* para significar transpor um obstáculo ou distância. A preferência parece-me especialmente forte no caso de *saltar* um obstáculo — *pular o muro* ou *pular um parágrafo* soa-me estranho. *O gato pulou-me para o colo* ou *pulou para cima do armário* até me parece bem, mas é muito mais comum usar-se *saltar* mesmo nestes casos. E preferimos *pular* quando falamos simplesmente de impulsão no ar sem objetivo de locomoção.

E já agora, também é *saltar* quando falamos de coisas inanimadas:

> Com a trepidação, saltou um parafuso que estava mal apertado
>
> A pressão fez saltar a rolha
>
> Saltou-me a tampa, e disse-lhe das boas (metafórico, ’perdi a paciência e explodi’)